# Adding a point with MapWinGIS

Tags: mapwingis

I need to create a mapping app with C# and stumbled upon MapWinGIS which looks like an appropriate tool. I have a minimal app working, pulling tiles from OpenStreetMap.

I want to plot a point on the map. I thought it would be as easy as calling DrawPoint(), but it's not working:

```
AxMap.DrawPoint(-100, 32, 10, Convert.ToUInt32(ColorTranslator.ToOle(Color.Red)));
```

Instead of drawing a point at map long (32, -100), the point appears to be at lat/lon of (0, 0).

Here's the full function:

```
public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            AxMap.CursorMode = tkCursorMode.cmPan;
            AxMap.InertiaOnPanning = tkCustomState.csFalse;
            AxMap.Projection = tkMapProjection.PROJECTION_GOOGLE_MERCATOR;
            AxMap.TileProvider = tkTileProvider.OpenHumanitarianMap;
            AxMap.KnownExtents = tkKnownExtents.keUSA;

            int d = AxMap.NewDrawing(tkDrawReferenceList.dlSpatiallyReferencedList);
            AxMap.DrawPoint(-100, 32, 10, Convert.ToUInt32(ColorTranslator.ToOle(Color.Red)));

        }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured this out. I needed to call DegreesToProj before plotting the point:

```
double lat = 32;
double lon = -100;
double projX = -2; //dummy value
double projY = -3; //dummy values
bool bSuccess = AxMap.DegreesToProj(lon, lat, ref projX, ref projY);
if (bSuccess)
{
    AxMap.DrawPoint(projX, projY, pixels, color);
}
```

Hope this helps someone.